# Yo dawg, I heard you like betas (iOS9 edition)

Tags: discussion, ios-app, feedback

iOS 9 is coming out pretty soon and I finally managed to get an iOS 9 build of our app out for testing.  Now I just need testers.  If you're one of the surprising 7% of our app users running an iOS9 beta, please consider joining our poorly described "alpha or wait, maybe it's beta" channel and let me know everything I broke.

### Big things that are working:

- Split screen mode works across the iPad.
- Questions you've looked at get populated into search.  This also means you <strike>Apple fanboys</strike> savvy consumers can now look at a question on your phone and then open it up on your iPad or Mac running Yosemite.
- The new system font is used across the app.

### Big things that may have broken:

- Literally everything.  Even if you're using iOS8, I've done some pretty big changes.

### Things I still want to implement:

- Use the new Safari view controller for any link opened in the app.  This should *drastically* improve Google/OAuth login.
- Fully adopt App Transport Security (probably not for a while as this depends on the above and would kill non-secure images in posts, similar to HTTPS browsing.)
- Other cool stuff?  If there's a sweet iOS 9 feature you want implemented, please share.

### Pretty screenshots

[image: Universal search showing viewed questions]

[image: iPad showing split view with Safari on the right]

[image: iPad showing split view now with Safari on the left and SE on the right]

### How to Sign Up

To register for α/β/? testing [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).  If you are already an α/β/? 
tester for the iOS app, dig up that old email on your iDevice and dive right in or sign up again if you can't find it.

After you register we will send you an e-mail with instructions on how to 
download the app on your iDevice. **The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient.**

Once you've downloaded, trust rules have changed for enterprise apps; you have to go into Settings > General > Profile and confirm that you trust it.

### Providing Feedback

As with the beta, crash reports will be automatically reported back to us 
using [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com). Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app). (For reporting purposes, the app version number can be displayed in the app by tapping the question mark near the bottom of the menu).

As always, we welcome your feedback and are committed to building the best mobile app possible for browsing the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Should we report bugs as separate questions or as answers on here? I've added three bugs as questions today

Comment: @AshleyMedway Considering that meta questions tagged as "bug" get added to their bug list, I'd say keep adding them as questions... and the question says: "Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [tag:ios-app]." You can't tag answers, so it has to be a question.