# Occasionally cannot add tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app

To reproduce:

1. Ask a new question
2. Give the question a title
3. Click in body and try to scroll down to tags

The tags box keeps hiding under the quick action buttons (Bold, Italics, etc.)

If you try to submit you question without tags it then forces you to add them, however you then have to wait 60 seconds before you can post the question.

You can add tags if you click the tags box before giving your question a title.

App version 1.3.2.225
iOS 9

Comment: What is your iOS version?

Comment: Oh, iOS 9 is still totally buggy there's a whole discussion about it

Comment: Oops, no dupe but you [can join the beta testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264408/yo-dawg-i-heard-you-like-betas-ios9-edition) and help hunt those bugs down. :)

Comment: You still see a dupe banner on top? I removed the vote.

Comment: Yeah it's gone now, I think we just commented at the same time then :P

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the iOS9 GM.  Can you confirm?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in iOS9 where keyboard frame change notifications aren't sent when the keyboard accessory view changes. ([rdar://22383652](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6136473212420096))  I'm guessing this is a regression from the whole "make the keyboard independent of the app" thing.

I'm hoping this will be fixed by GM otherwise I'm going to do a hack where I add input accessory views for each text field and have those views monitor their parent view's center for changes.

Temporary workarounds include:

- Tapping the body first so the keyboard inset includes the toolbar height.
- Doing an orientation change so the keyboard height changes.
- Probably doing a full preview then popping the preview.

Not sure why you're getting a 60 second timeout for no tags.  I should be validating that client side.  I'll take a look.

Comment: The 60 second issue is due to API rate limiting, isn't it? If you can nudge Kasra to follow your lead, [it would be awesome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262306/waiting-60-seconds-every-time-i-make-a-mistake-when-posting-a-question-is-a-pain). :-)